# Annotate stacked barplot matplotlib and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a simple Data Frame that stores the results of a survey. The columns are:

```
| Age | Income | Satisfaction |
```

all of them contains values between `1` and `5` (categorical). I managed to generate a stacked barplot that shows distribution of `Satisfaction` values across people of different age.
The code is:

```
#create a random df
data = []
for i in range(500):
    sample = {"age" : random.randint(0,5), "income" : random.randint(1,5), "satisfaction" : random.randint(1,5)}
data.append(sample)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#group by age
counter = df.groupby('age')['satisfaction'].value_counts().unstack()
#calculate the % for each age group 
percentage_dist = 100 * counter.divide(counter.sum(axis = 1), axis = 0)
percentage_dist.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

This generates the following, desired, plot:
[image]

However, it's difficult to compare if the `green` subset (percentage) of `Age-0` is higher than the one in `Age-2`. Therefore, is there a way of adding the percentage on top of each sub-section of the barplot. Something like this, but for every single bar:
[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One option is to iterate over the patches in order to obtain their width, height and bottom-left coordinates and use this values to place the label at the center of the corresponding bar.

To do this, the axes returned by the pandas bar method must be stored.

```
ax = percentage_dist.plot.bar(stacked=True)
for p in ax.patches:
    width, height = p.get_width(), p.get_height()
    x, y = p.get_xy() 
    ax.text(x+width/2, 
            y+height/2, 
            '{:.0f} %'.format(height), 
            horizontalalignment='center', 
            verticalalignment='center')
```

Here, the annotated value is set to 0 decimals, but this can be easily modified.

The output plot generated with this code is the following:

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer for me, including the linked posts.  I added:
 ```if height==0: 
    continue```  
for cases where a catagory does not appear in a stack (which gives anomalous 0% lables at the bottom).

Comment: Glad it could be of help! I hadn't actually given much thought to this answer, I have edited to improve the label placement, now they are centered.

Comment: You can change the format of the number to {:.0%} as well

Comment: Using this method how would you calculate the percentages when each column is of a different height (column patches don't add to 100 - don't represent percentages)

Comment: I was able to do this by enumerating the patches then using the index to index into the categories. However this doesn't feel clean...