# plot stacked percentage barchart matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Let's say I have the following dataframe with two columns:
label: can be -1, 0 or 1.
years_of_expereicen: can be 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

```
label   SSP_years_of_experience
22640   -1.0    5.0
181487  1.0 3.0
327672  0.0 9.0
254919  0.0 6.0
136942  1.0 10.0
```

My goal here is to use this dataframe to create a percentage stacked barchart where the x-axis is years of experience and the bars are different colors each consisting of one years of experience value.  In other words, we have 10 possible values on the x-axis and then three bars for each value of different colors that map to each of the labels.  The y-axis should be in percent.

I would knoew how to do this in R (with ggplot), but I'm new to matplotlib and somewhat new to python.

Bonus points where I can pass in the two columns as variables (eg. x,y).  MOre bonus points for how to display the number of observations in each bar as text in the chart.

Answer (score 3):

If you data frame is `pandas`, try:

```
exp_name = 'year_of_experience'
label_name = 'label'
new_df = (df.groupby(exp_name)[label_name]
            .value_counts(normalize=True)
            .sort_index()
            .unstack()
         )

new_df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Toy data frame:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'label': np.random.choice([-1,0,1], size=1000, replace=True),
                   'year_of_experience': np.random.randint(0,10, 1000)})
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Bonus points: What is years of experience and label are passed in as variables.  How would I do it in that case?

Comment: Hi Quang Hoang, also how would you display the number of observations in each bar?

Comment: @ben890 see here for the annotations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50161387/1011724. Also, I would recommend you put all of this in a function so something like `def plot_stacked(df, exp_name, label_name, annotations=True):`